# Generation of documentation comments in AppCode 3.0 like in IntelliJ

Tags: objective-c, documentation, code-generation, appcode

Is there any way in `AppCode 3.0` to generate documentation comments like in `IntelliJ`?

For example, in `IntelliJ` I can type a method:

```
public int method(float number){
    // magic
}
```

And when above it, I will type: `/**`, IDE will generate me code like this:

```
/**
*
* @param number
* @return
*/
public int method(float number){
    // magic 
}
```

In `AppCode 3.0` after doing similar trick, I only get something like this:

```
/**
*
*/
- (int)method:(float)number;
```

I have checked `Preferences/Smart Keys/Insert documentation comment stub` and it is checked.

Comment: For now I have decided to use: `VVDocumenter` which is a great plugin for xCode: https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode I hope AppCode will have this feature in the nearest future.

Comment: You can propose this here [link](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC)

Comment: How about C on AppCode? Any documentation tools? Nothing fancy.. I just want to put the arguments in place for me, when I type `/**` and then enter!

Comment: Have you made a feature request with JetBrains?

Comment: I have made a feature request for documentation support back in 2012 and so far they didn't add any kind of feature.

[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3526](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-3526)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature wasn't available in AppCode 3.0, but has been added in version 2016.2 so upgrading will fix your issue. From [the release notes](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/whatsnew/#v2016-2-documentation):

> Generate documentation comments for Objective-C/C++ methods in no time, simply by pressing /**, /*! or /// and have parameter names inserted into the comment stub automatically.

Comment: Any solutions to have this working with Swift in latest appCode?

Comment: Apparently they still need to implement generating documentation comments in Swift. You can track the progress here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14887.